# running xelatex from www-data with sudo

Tags: errors, compiling, php

I encountered a strange compilation result when running xelatex from a php script. The website is supposed to compile latex code (with xelatex) but always added a strange "<" sign in the middle of the page. The exact same tex code compiled flawlessly when compiled under a normal user.
I could solve the problem by using sudo.

```
sudo -u latexuser /usr/bin/xelatex -interaction nonstopmode <TEXFILE>
```

and in sudoers the line to prevent password promt

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xelatex
```

Now www-data compiles the texfiles as a normal user without making trouble.

PS: adding cache directory --- TEXMFCACHE=:/.. --- did not solve the problem.

Example of compilation error: between "principle" and "that" the added < sign:
[image: xelatex with compilation error]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "a strange < sign in the middle of the page"? Is there anything else on the page? Could you show a screenshot? Anything in the log file produced by xelatex on such a run? Does the same issue appear with pdflatex and lualatex?

Comment: Is it only one document that does this, or do all documents produce the same output?

Comment: All documents -- and I tried about 50 -- had the same strange sign in the upper middle part of the pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (as already mentioned):

`sudo -u latexuser /usr/bin/xelatex -interaction nonstopmode <TEXFILE>`

and in sudoers the line to prevent password promt

`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xelatex`